Integral of $1/\sin(y)$ in Wolfram Mathematica vs. Wolfram|Alpha
I was looking at solution of this ode using step-by-step in Wolfram|Alpha:

But in Mathematica V 14
Integrate[Csc[y], y]

gives
-ArcTanh[Cos[y]]

How can I show that -ArcTanh[Cos[y]] is the same as -Log[Cos[y/2]] + Log[Sin[y/2]]?
I tried TrigToExp, but that still does not give the exact result as Wolfram|Alpha:
Integrate[Csc[y], y]
TrigToExp[%]
% /. any1_*Log[x_] + any2_*Log[y_] :> any1*Log[ExpToTrig[x]] + any2*Log[ExpToTrig[y]]


Plotting them gives
Plot[{1/2  Log[1 - Cos[y]] - 1/2  Log[1 + Cos[y]], -Log[Cos[y/2]] + 
   Log[Sin[y/2]]}, {y, -2  Pi, 2 Pi}, PlotLegends -> {"MMA", "alpha"}]


The question is: How can I obtain the antiderivative shown by Wolfram|Alpha in Wolfram Mathematica?

Differentiation shows that both give Csc[y].  Note that they can differ by a constant.

@mikado I do understand they are both correct antiderivatives. But my question is how to derive the Wolfram alpha answer from the Mathematica answer using transformation.  I thought Wolfram alpha use Mathematica to do the integration.

Tanh[-(-Log[Cos[y/2]] + Log[Sin[y/2]])] // TrigToExp // FullSimplify  yields Cos[y].  You should remember that Log[x] has a branch cut discontinuity in the complex z plane running from -Infinity to 0, since it isn't uniquely defined in the full complex plane, while FullSimplify yields generically correct results (it doesn't work as e.g. Reduce is supposed to do).

The Wolfram Alpha solution gives meaningful results on the interval 0 to π.  Limiting the range to this, we get
Assuming[0 < Y < π,
 Integrate[Csc[y], {y, π/2, Y}]]
(* Log[Tan[Y/2]] *)

This is the same as the Wolfram Alpha solution
Assuming[0 < y < π, 
 1/2   Log[1 - Cos[y]] - 1/2   Log[1 + Cos[y]] == Log[Tan[y/2]] // 
  FullSimplify]
(* True *)


Thanks. I just do not understand why to did Integrate[Csc[y], {y, π/2, Y}]] I mean, where did the Pi/2 come from. But will look more into it to try to figure it out.

This was based on the plot in the question, which showed that Wolfram Alpha result was zero at π/2.  I wanted a result that agreed on the interval 0 to π

Do you have any idea why Alpha gave this anti-derivative though? Mathematica gives -ArcTanh[Cos[y]] and I have thought Alpha uses Mathematica for integration. But may be it uses AI now for integration also.

This is interesting and subtle, but we see this thing quite a lot.  Mathematica has to make a fairly arbitrary choice about which branch cut to take in the complex plane.  We can't validly integrate through the singularities at multiples of pi, so we will get different answers depending on whether we go above or below them.  Try plotting the real and imaginary parts of the Alpha answer.  Even minor changes to the version of Mathematica can change the answer when there is a choice of right answers.
